# How to disable "special commands" in node.js REPL?

Tags: javascript, node.js, console, read-eval-print-loop

**Problem** Node REPL has some ["special commands"](https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html#repl_repl_features) like `.break` and `.save`. I *never* use these, but I do *very* frequently try and paste into the REPL code that's formatted like so:

```
words.append('ul')
    .classed('my-class', true)
    .selectAll('li.new-class')
    .data((tuple, tupleIdx) => obj[tupleIdx])
    .enter()
    .append('li')
    .classed('new-class', true)
    .text(d => '' + foo(d));
```

(This is d3.js code but similar things happen when using Promises, a chain of `.then(...)`s starting on each line.)

Of course node complains about "invalid REPL keyword" when it sees `.classed` or `.then` on its own line and proceeds to print a sequence of error messages several screens long.

**Tenuous pseudo-workaround** I've worked around this with a regexp in Vim that moves any whitespace between closing parens and dots to after the dot (`:%s/)\n\(\s*\)\./).\r\1/` for completeness) but this is tedious and often I want to copy-paste from a browser and not switch to Vim to reformat some code.

**Question** Is there any way to disable node REPL "features" which, while well-intentioned, conflict with standard JavaScript practices, such as lines starting with dots?

Or is this too complicated for a terminal application, and if so, is there a way I can communicate with the node REPL via a browser's JS console (not [node-monkey](https://github.com/jwarkentin/node-monkey) which only handles `console.log`)

**PS.** This question is mainly about lines starting with `.` but another such conflict is `_` (worked around thankfully by [n_](https://github.com/borisdiakur/n_)).

Comment: While I no longer use D3 or Promises much, I still run into this a lot with parsing files, for example, `fs.readFileSync('file', 'utf8').trim().split('\n').filter(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [make your own custom REPL](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/REPL/how-to-create-a-custom-repl/). That option should give you maximal control over how your repl behaves.

Since the main problem here is pasting multi-line code into the default repl, as a workaround, try using [the `.editor` special command](https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html).

> Enter editor mode (`Ctrl+D` to finish, `Ctrl+C` to cancel).

It's also mentioned in the answer to [this question about writing multiple lines in the node repl](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29203892/11107541)

If you're also interested in saving keystrokes, when entering the editor, autocomplete seems to kick in after typing ".ed" so you can shave off three keystrokes in that sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply delete the command from the instance:

```js
const replServer = repl.start(/* ... */)
delete replServer.commands.load;
```

You can even define the whole `commands` object, take a look at the reference implementation:

https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/main/lib/repl.js

Answer (score 0):

Here's something tentative: using [node-copy-paste](https://github.com/xavi-/node-copy-paste), I wrote a tiny module that allows me to `paste()` the contents of clipboard and `eval`s it after fixing lines starting with `.`.

This goes in `paste.js`:

```
var cp = require('copy-paste'); // npm install node-copy-paste

module.exports = function() {
  return eval(cp.paste().replace(/\n\s*\./g, "."));
};
```

Then in node REPL, `paste = require('./paste'); paste()` will make it go. Very brittle but it might solve the problem often enough to be valuable.