# node's REPL doesn't recognizes a block code

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to write a simple code in node's `REPL` but am coming across some difficulties:

When typing commands one line at a time everything is working fine,
but when wrapping it with the parenthesis block `{ ... code ... }`
(and hitting enter after each line) I'm getting an error after the closing one (`}`).

[image]

As you can see in the image I've added - executing the same code, one line at a time, is working fine.

Comment: Hint: `{}` is an object literal

Comment: node v5 wont even close the block so your older version is closer! why would you want to do this anyway? I suspect there is a good reason why a REPL will not execute arbitrary blocks of codes like that

Comment: Thanks @nem, but I want to write a code block (testing js not in a single line via the REPL).

Comment: @MattStyles - don't know node v5 (but would look into it if time permits),
the reason is written above, and luckily - we can do it :)

Comment: The extra/closing semi-colon also works in node v5! Multi-line away! I normally just execute a small file, but I can see how multiline is useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it,
I should have added a `;` after the parenthesis.

This is the result of running the code now:

[image]

Comment: This won't work since Node 10.9. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52986981/3731501

Answer (score 2):

Your interpreter thinks you're going to make an object literal, like `{ var: x }` would be. `{ var x; }` is not a good object syntax, as there should be a colon after the indentifier `var`, not `x`. Thus, `SyntaxError`.

You can force the parser to think it's a code block after all by prepending any of the hints that it is actually a code block:

```
label: { var x; }

if (true) { var x; }

do { var x; } while (false);
```

EDIT: Also, note that there is no good reason to do this. If you are not using a code block as a statement group for a flow control statement, or as a target for a label, it is utterly useless (and a potential source of hard-to-track bugs, as you found).

In other languages, you might be controlling the scope of variables (I expect you wanted to make sure `x` was not visible outside the block?). In JavaScript, *only functions have scope*. Thus, to isolate variables from the surrounding environment, you need a function:

```
{
  var x1;
};
x1; // undefined

(function() {
  var x2;
})();
x2; // Uncaught ReferenceError: x is not defined
```